# How to pass values from one test case into another in SOAP UI REST project?

Tags: groovy, jax-rs, soapui

I have 2 test-cases one will call a service and get a JSON response and in the second test-case, I would like to use the value received from the first test-case.Is it possible to do with Groovy scripts?

For INSIACE:

first service repose is like below:

{
 token : "dddfds",
 tokenExpiry : 10
}

I would like to get value of token from above JSON in another test case.

Comment: Basic thumb rule is that each and every test case should be independent.

Comment: I agree with @Rao. What you should do is to use your second test case as a sub test case of the first one (in order to avoid to add too many new steps) and pass the token as a 'parameter', ie. a custom variable of your second test case. Then you'll be able to use it in your groovy script ...

Comment: I agree with the previous comments. However there can be scenarios where reusing values from another testcase may be useful. This is fairly straightforward, but looking at your track record, and how rare it is for you to accept the answers you get, I won't even bother writing an answer here.

Comment: You do not necessarily have to use groovy to transfer values from one test case to another, You can simply use the Property Transfer test step, setup the source by extracting the values using XPath or JSONPath and set the target at a TestCase level or the Project level using custom properties, You can then call these values in your subsequent call using ${#TestCase#token} or ${#Project#token} accordingly